# Tensorflow pose estimation strange behaviour

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, computer-vision, pose-estimation

I am trying to detect body parts/landmarks from pictures but I'm facing an issue.
For some reason it prints the knee points even when there's no knees in the picture.

Any ideas how and why to fix this ? Or what is the better/faster way to detect body points. Thanks

[image]

Here's my code :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np 
import cv2

image_path = "test3.jpg"
image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image)

input_image = tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
input_image = tf.image.resize_with_pad(input_image, 192, 192)

model_path = "movenet_lightning_fp16.tflite"
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

input_image = tf.cast(input_image, dtype=tf.uint8)
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_image.numpy())
interpreter.invoke()
keypoints = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])

width = 640
height = 640

KEYPOINT_EDGES = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (5, 7),
    (7, 9), (6, 8), (8, 10), (5, 6), (5, 11), (6, 12), (11, 12), (11, 13),
    (13, 15), (12, 14), (14, 16)]

input_image = tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
input_image = tf.image.resize_with_pad(input_image, width, height)
input_image = tf.cast(input_image, dtype=tf.uint8)

image_np = np.squeeze(input_image.numpy(), axis=0)
image_np = cv2.resize(image_np, (width, height))
image_np = cv2.cvtColor(image_np, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

for keypoint in keypoints[0][0]:
    x = int(keypoint[1] * width)
    y = int(keypoint[0] * height)

    cv2.circle(image_np, (x, y), 4, (0, 0, 255), -1)

for edge in KEYPOINT_EDGES:
    
    x1 = int(keypoints[0][0][edge[0]][1] * width)
    y1 = int(keypoints[0][0][edge[0]][0] * height)

    x2 = int(keypoints[0][0][edge[1]][1] * width)
    y2 = int(keypoints[0][0][edge[1]][0] * height)

    cv2.line(image_np, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
print(keypoints)
cv2.imshow("pose estimation", image_np)
cv2.waitKey()
```

These are the 17 points that are printing....

```
[[[[0.14580254 0.44932607 0.49171054]
[0.12085933 0.48325056 0.76345515]
[0.12439865 0.4332864  0.6319262 ]
[0.14748134 0.54644144 0.69355035]
[0.1498755  0.4215817  0.47992003]
[0.36506626 0.63139945 0.85730654]
[0.34724534 0.3317352  0.7910126 ]
[0.61043286 0.6646681  0.76448154]
[0.5989852  0.29230848 0.8800807 ]
[0.8311419  0.7306837  0.7297675 ]
[0.8425422  0.26081967 0.63438255]
[0.85355556 0.5752684  0.79087543]
[0.8471971  0.37801507 0.79199016]
[0.9836348  0.5910964  0.00867963]
[1.0096381  0.33657807 0.01041293]
[0.86401206 0.7281677  0.03190452]
[0.8798219  0.265369   0.01451936]]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pose models always output all points that they supposed to detect. If there is not knee in the picture, model estimates the approximate point of knee in picture and give that point as output but confidence score of that point would be very low. So you can filter points by confidence score.
you can add a variable as a threshold for confidence and filter point with it. I call it `conf_thrs` in code bellow:

```
conf_thrs = 0.5

for keypoint in keypoints[0][0]:
    if keypoint[2] > conf_thrs:
        # if confidence score is more than 0.5 do the following.
        x = int(keypoint[1] * width)
        y = int(keypoint[0] * height)

        cv2.circle(image_np, (x, y), 4, (0, 0, 255), -1)
```

And do the same for loop through `KEYPOINT_EDGES`.

Comment: Interesting ! I that's good to know ! how am I finding that confidence score ?!

Comment: Usually first and second elements of output are x and y and the last one is confidence. For example confidence of last point that you printed is 0.01451936.

Comment: Ok...so 0.00867963 should be the left knee....and 0.01041293 would be the right knee...how i can filter it than ?

Comment: Add `if` statement inside you loop through keypoints. `if keypoint[2] > conf_thrs:`

Comment: not sure i understand...

Comment: I will edit my answer and add code to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239914/discussion-between-andie31-and-mohammad-khoshbin).